# How to restrict list column for the particular group?

Tags: list, permissions

I have created one list, I want to restrict few column to particular group.
Is there any way to do it? Or any other options like JavaScript. I am not familiar with JavaScript though.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint does not support field-level security.  With JavaScript the best you can do is obfuscate them somewhat, but smart users will find a way to get that obfuscated data.  If your data is sensitive, you do NOT want to do this.  Find another way to architect your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As derek stated, nothing available out of the box.

There are purchasable third party add-ons that do this though. http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx